# How to get back input value onblur with Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new with Angular and wanted to know how can I handle the following issue :

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{add_item.value}}" onfocus="this.value=''" onblur="this.value={{add_item.value}}">
```

of course this doesn't work.

I would like to get back the first value onblur if the input is empty.

Any advice ?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are interested in , I made an ugly thing but it works. I'm storing the original value in placeholder and using it onblur like this :

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder ="{{add_item.value}}"  onfocus="this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.placeholder"
```

Answer (score 0):

The short: You need to store the original value somewhere to retrieve when you need it.

Even shorter: Use https://github.com/betsol/angular-input-modified